# How to get a local file size with in a Java web handler?

Tags: java

How to get a local file length within a web handler?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xxx.iso", method = { RequestMethod.HEAD })
public void doChunkedHEAD(HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        URL fileUrl = servletContext.getResource(filename);
        File fileObj = new File(fileUrl.toString());
        long fileSize = fileObj.length();
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileSize));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

The `fileSize` is always 0. And the `fileUrl` is something like this:

```
file:/C:/xxx.iso
```

And `fileObj.exists()` returns `false`. But the file does exists as `C:\xxx.iso`.

If I use absolute local path, the size can be obtained:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xxx.iso", method = { RequestMethod.HEAD })
public void doChunkedHEAD(HttpServletResponse response) {
    File fileObj = new File("C:\\xxx.iso");
    long fileSize = fileObj.length();
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileSize));
}
```

Why?

I am using Java 1.7.76.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to did it with below code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xxx.iso", method = { RequestMethod.HEAD })
public void doChunkedHEAD(HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        String localAppRootPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
        Path filePath = Paths.get(localAppRootPath, "xxx.iso");
        File fileObj = new File(filePath.toString());
        long fileSize = fileObj.length();
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileSize));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

But I still don't know why I can't use `URL` instead.